# Find all integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 42$.

Tags: number-theory

> Find all integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 42$.

After some experimentation, none of the numbers I try even work. I tried $x=3,y=2$ and $z=8,$ for instance. However, I know this is a Diophantine equation with a solution.

> Is there some way to solve this problem w/o using a computer program or guess-and-check/trial-and-error?
>
> Edit: This definitely isn't an easy problem.

Comment: if you rewrite it as $x = \sqrt[3]{42-y^3-z^3}$ you'll realize that to get $x\in Z$, you need to find y and z in such way that the cuberoot value is in $Z$.

Comment: Not without a computer. In fact, the first known solution $$\small (−80538738812075974)^3+(80435758145817515)^3+(12602123297335631)^3=42$$
is found recently by a cluster of over 500,000 computers. [ref](https://www.sciencealert.com/the-sum-of-three-cubes-problem-has-been-solved-for-42)

Comment: @achillehui it was kind of you to send the link... because I was thinking where you found such a computer able to solve this... :-) but I have another question: is it possible to solve the problem of the question WITH computer? I mean to find ALL solutions? I don't think we are closed to that.

Comment: Note that it's possible to find lots of off-by-1 solution candidates by doing $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{42-y^3-z^3} \rfloor$ and choosing $y\in Z$ and $z\in Z$. This property might make the equation useful even with no actual solutions are found.

Comment: @AnatoliyR According to a book  (Henri Cohen's Number theory Vol I, page 380 ) on my bookshelf, it is conjectured that for any integer $n$ not congruent to $\pm 4 \pmod 9$, there are infinitely many solutions to the equation $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = n$. If this conjecture is true, then it is impossible to find all solution with computer alone.

Comment: not quite right, the question is what to call a solution and what is not: let's say, human finds a constructive sequence (e.g. defined with some explicit or recurrent expression) for all such solutions and proves that with a help of computer. I know this is off-topic, but is it impossible?

Comment: Why is this "at first glance" an easy problem ? A diophantine equation with 3 variables and degree $3$ is not easy at all. Note that it has been proven that there is no general algorithm to decide whether a diophantine equation has a solution or not, so we always have to expect difficulties unless we have special cases we know that they can be solved relatively easy.

Comment: I guess that the solution was not found by pure brute force (which would be very surprising even considering the huge computational power), but basically brute force was very probably applied. Several necessary conditions should have been found to reduce the number of possible solutions, but still it was not an easy task at all to find this solution.